# Wireless not working on old notebook

Tags: wireless, drivers, versions

Running slacker 6.1 on old comp. Have Linksys WPC54GS netbook adapter (wireless) and can't find a driver to make it work. It used to work but I rebooted with a different Version. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have activated the Wireless driver? If you tried to, and it did not work, go to: Settings -> Programs and Updates -> Additional Drivers. (Sorry for bad English)